# Find the value of $\sqrt3\csc 20^o -\sec 20^o$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $$\sqrt3\csc 20^o -\sec 20^o.$$

How do you solve this? Please help. Don't even know how to start this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861095/can-dfrac-sqrt3-sin20-circ-dfrac1-cos20-circ-have-two-va

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}\sqrt3 \csc 20^o -\sec 20^o&=&  {\sqrt3\over \sin 20^o} -{1\over \cos 20^o}\\
&&\\
 &=&{\sqrt3 \cos 20^o - \sin 20^o\over \cos 20^o\sin 20^o}\\
&&\\
 &=&4{\cos 30^o \cos 20^o - \sin 20^o\sin 30^o \over 2\cos 20^o\sin 20^o}\\ 
&& \\
&=&4{ \cos 50^o \over \sin 40^o}= 4\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Aren't we supposed to provide hints instead of full solutions?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$
\sqrt3 \csc x - \sec x = \frac{\sqrt3}{\sin x} - \frac{1}{\cos x},
$$

and $\displaystyle 20^o = \frac{\pi}{9}$ radians.